# Prevent form submission in react with Tags input component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

I know many variations of this question has already been asked but my problem isn't as simple as using `event.preventDefault()` or perhaps it is and my events are somehow getting tangled up.

Problem: I have a tag helper component that adds a hidden input field with this new tag information when a new tag is entered by pressing 'Enter'. When this happens, my form submits which is the default behavior. I do not want that. This event takes places at the child component level, not at the parent level where the form markup is located. When i add `event.preventDefault()` at the parent level this does indeed prevent a form submission however this locks up my form and cannot submit a form with the default behavior. When i try this at the child level it ignores the `event.preventDefault()`. If i try an inline `onSubmit` on the form and `useState` as a conditional and update this state `onClick` for the submit button the updated value is lagging behind. I tried using `useEffect` but i got an infinite loop. I simply want to prevent empty required fields from being submitted while retaining normal behavior. (Im using [Remix](https://remix.run) which doesnt require things like redux, sagas, axios etc)

Code sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-lederberg-3pkriq-3pkriq

Some code from my child component

onEnter to create hidden input fields with tag info:

```
    const onEnter = (e) => {
        if (e.code === 'Enter' && inputValue && valid) {
            e.preventDefault();
            setTags([...tags, { id: String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)), name: inputValue }]);
            setInputValue('');
        }
    };
```

Pill with hidden input:

```
    const Pill = ({
        onClickHandler, name, value, children,
    }) => {

        return (
            <div title="remove" onClick={(e) => onClickHandler(e)}>
                {children}<span>X</span>
                <input type="hidden" name={name} value={value.name} />
            </div>
            
        );
    };
```

render for child component:

```
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                placeholder={placeholder}
                value={inputValue}
                onKeyUp={(e) => onEnter(e)}
                onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
            />
            <div>
                {tags
                    && tags.map((item) => (
                        <Pill
                            value={item}
                            onClickHandler={onDelete}
                            key={item.name}
                            name={name}
                        >
                            {item.name}
                        </Pill>
                    ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

I've been stuck on this for weeks and after trying dozens of workarounds such as HTML5 required attribute, validation libraries, custom server side validation, `event.stopPropagation`, inline onSubmit and same issue persists. At this point I think the problem may be where the location of the event is firing. When i log the `event.type` at the parent level after i hit `Enter` i see `undefined` and then `KeyUp` if that helps. Maybe i need to pass the event up from the child? Any direction or clues would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Simply changing my event listener from `onKeyUp` to `onKeyDown` solved my issue. The bug was in the order of the events when keys are pressed. They trigger in order from `keydown`, `keyup`, `keypress`. `keyup` fires once while `keydown` and `keypress` fires multiple times. Somewhere between those two, my event was not being correctly captured.

Explanation: https://thisthat.dev/keydown-vs-keypress-vs-keyup/

Fixed Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-lederberg-3pkriq-forked-79og2h